# Browsers only using 1% of the internet capacity when downloading files

Tags: wireless-networking

This just happened yesterday. I tried to download some of the materials for my courses, but my browser only seems to be using 1% of my WiFi capacity. It couldn't even reach 1mb/s of download speed.

I tested on another laptop, and it got 13mb/s of download speed.

Any ideas of what could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: there are always to sides of a medal - one is your internet bandwith and the other one is the bandwith of the server you are getting information from. Some mirrors or even CDNs for example are just slow, resulting in a slow download rate, even if you've got a decent internet connection.

But you've also mentioned, that you are getting speeds which are x13 better on another machine in your LAN. This could have multiple reasons which I cannot go into detail since I've got to less information about your hard- and software-configuration:

- Multiple antennas in a MIMO-config (**M**ultiple **I**nput **M**ultiple **O**utput) on the other WLAN-Chipset
- Other WLAN-Chipset and/or other drivers (in general you could try updating the WLAN drivers)
- Misconfiguration in QoS (**Q**uality **o**f **S**ervice) settings, but if you haven't tweaked settings manually, this should be alright
- Environmental differences (e.g. steel reinforced walls, poor WLAN converage in that specific area inside your house/flat
- etc.